# How to create emulator for devices other than nexus?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In AVD manager, under "Device" drop down only Nexus phones are available.

How can i create emulator/device for Samsung Galaxy Grand ?

Is there any way that we can download devices ?

I have created a new device with "Create device" option with Galaxy grand's specs. But some how i have the doubt whether it behaves exactly same as the Galaxy Grand device or not.

Comment: There is a button which says "Create"... Then google for getting the specs of the device you want to emulate and use those specs to create your emulator.

Comment: @DerGol...lum Thanks for the quick reply... I already created the device like that. But some how i have the doubt that whether it will behave exactly like Samsung Galaxy Grand device or not. So i wanted to know that is there any way to download different devices directly. Updated the question as well.

Comment: `whether it behaves exactly same` - no. It does not. Only real devices behave same.

Comment: I created device with the following specs:
Screen size: 5.0
Resolution: 480X800
RAM: 1 GB

While starting the emulator, it is stuck at boot animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more control on your emulator, I recommend using another emulator such as Genymotion..

Genymotion allows you to download the device you want from plenty of devices and APIs and also it's much faster than the default emulator..

[This article](http://www.thedevline.com/2014/04/how-to-set-up-genymotion-fast-easy.html) explains the features and installation of Genymotion..

You can download it from the official web site https://www.genymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

Although with the **AVD** you wont be able to get it **done**.

But instead you can customize the configurations for **Samsung Galaxy Grand**

If still you want to have more control on your emulator, then you must use other emulators such as [**BlueStack**](http://www.bluestacks.com/), [**Genymotion**](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)......